# Help find a childhood book

Tags: story-identification, novel, books, childrens-novel

Okay so from what I remember the story takes place in a (boring?) gray world and the main character is a girl (maybe around 12). I don't remember how but the girl ended up in a different (realm? world?) place that had a beautiful garden. She stayed there and I remember reading a part where she looks into the water (I'm pretty sure she was on a bridge looking into the river) and is surprised to see that her hair is turning green from staying in the beautiful place for so long. This book has pictures and it's a children's book. I really want to find it again because it's bugging me that I can't remember it. Please help!!